# Aside is going down only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have recently designed a responsive WP Theme for my blog and there only in Chrome, a aside is falling from header. I see, to stick it into header wrapper, I can add clearfix to header `class=wrapper`. That is clear but question is why it is coming down where it does not have much height.

I have tested in FF and IE and it is working there. In IE, it is working in IE10 and IE9. In IE8 many things are broken so please do not look there.

`<aside>` with `top-bar-section` is going down compared to the normal flow. The class `top-bar-section` was having `display:inline-block` and `float:right` and I made it to `display:block`. I saw that when I toggle in Chrome Dev tool with `display:inline-block / float:right` then problem was going away so i just took a chance with `display:block` as float makes div a block element!

Now, toggle in dev tool of chrome of Float:right is not helping but toggling of `display:block` help place it at right place.

With Toggling, I meant that un-selecting that property in dev tool and selecting again.

[image: snapshot of problem]

HTML markup group:

[image: HTML structure]

[**Online Example**](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2013/12/a-lightweight-css-framework-from-yahoo.html): Issue is not happening on Home page.

**Update**: I saw also, somewhere  is overflowing horizontally.

Comment: What is the problem with changing display:block to display: inline-block ? If this works, use it!

Comment: That was also having the problem. I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: I also noticed that on different posts page , header is coming on different height. Left/right arrow key can be used to navigate.

Comment: Ok, I made it absolute and solved it. I don't want to use that but that 'blinking' feature on chrome was troubling.